# DES encryption/decryption in client/server using openssl

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, client-server, des

I need to perform DES encryption in server, send the encryption to the client 
and decrypt it in the client.

Server:

```
const EVP_CIPHER *c = EVP_des_cbc(); 
EVP_CIPHER_CTX  *x = malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(x);

EVP_EncryptInit (x, c, key, iv);        // initlizing encryption

EVP_EncryptUpdate (x, encryptedDataBuffer, &encryptedDataLength, dataBuffer, strlen(dataBuffer));
EVP_EncryptFinal (x,  encryptedDataBuffer + encryptedDataLength,  &encryptedDataLength);

write(client_sock , encryptedDataBuffer , encryptedDataLength);
printf("Encrypted Data Sent to Client\n");
```

Here server encrypts the data and sends it to client. So far so good.

Client:

```
serverDataLength = recv(sockfd , dataBuffer , MAXDATASIZE , 0);
printf("Encrypted Data is Received\n");

const EVP_CIPHER *c = EVP_des_cbc();    
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *x = malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(x);

EVP_DecryptInit(x, c, key, iv);
EVP_DecryptUpdate(x,  decryptedDataBuffer, &sizeOfDecryptedBuffer , dataBuffer,  serverDataLength);
EVP_DecryptFinal(x, decryptedDataBuffer+sizeOfDecryptedBuffer, &sizeOfDecryptedBuffer);

printf("\n\nDecrypted Data: %s\n", decryptedDataBuffer);
```

Client receives the data and decrypts it.

However the problem is when I print the decrypted data  in client, it prints some garbage values along with the decrypted data. How do I get rid of those garbage values? Client/Server works fine, no problem there.

I don't want to post the complete code here, it'll get messy. I am pretty sure the problem is somewhere in the posted code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have supplied wrong lengths to the procedures.

Try the following:

```
int ciphertext_len;

EVP_EncryptUpdate (x, encryptedDataBuffer, &encryptedDataLength,     dataBuffer, strlen(dataBuffer));
ciphertext_len = encryptedDataLength;

EVP_EncryptFinal (x,  encryptedDataBuffer + encryptedDataLength,  &encryptedDataLength);
ciphertext_len += encryptedDataLength;


int plaintext_len;

EVP_DecryptUpdate(x,  decryptedDataBuffer, &sizeOfDecryptedBuffer , dataBuffer,  ciphertext_len);
plaintext_len = sizeOfDecryptedBuffer;

EVP_DecryptFinal(x, decryptedDataBuffer+sizeOfDecryptedBuffer, &sizeOfDecryptedBuffer);
plaintext_len += sizeOfDecryptedBuffer;
```

Now print the decrypted data:

```
/* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
decryptedDataBuffer[plaintext_len] = '\0';

/* Show the decrypted text */
printf("Decrypted text is:\n");
printf("%s\n", decryptedDataBuffer);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think reason is simple.

In server you use `strlen()` for getting content length, so you have ignored terminating '\0' at end of your string. You decrypt your content and print it ignoring that terminating '\0'. So you print garbage from memory at end of decrypted message.

You need to send data **including terminating '\0'** by something like using `strlen(dataBuffer)+1`, or you need to **add** it to received content.

**2 side note:**

1. `DES` algorithm is a very insecure algorithm, **NEVER** use it.
2. In socket programming it is always suggested to send data length alongside data. For example, send 2 bytes that show encrypted data length and then send data. So you can manage data much better at client.

Comment: DES is considered insecure,because of it's short key length - 64 bits, effectively 56 bits. But 3DES with triple key length is considered very secure.

Comment: @малинчекуров yea, `3DES` is better, but as I rememeber, it is still much worse than something like `AES256`. But anyway, I guess we both agree that he should not use `DES`. :)

Comment: 3DES as a block-cipher itself can not be broken with the current technology. The major issue with 3DES is it's small block size which makes birthday-bounds attacks like Sweet32 applicable - you have to change the key every 32GB. This doesn't mean you have to forget about it, sure it has to be replaces by AES one day, but it still has it's applications today.

Comment: @малинчекуров There isn't really any reason to keep using 3DES though.  It's already been deprecated by a lot of common crypto libraries, doesn't have hardware acceleration (like AES does) and requires special implementation efforts to avoid things like the attack you outlined.  It's like recommending to use a horse and cart.  Sure, it gets you from A to B, but wouldn't you prefer to use a car?